PowerShell Script for Getting MFA Status
We use Microsoft 365 and are implementing MFA. I was looking for way to pull a report showing the status of each user. It looks like this can only be done with PowerShell. But the scripts I found either give only two statuses, 'Enabled' and 'Disabled' or gives incorrect statuses.
The script below incorrectly gives the 'Enabled' status of users with MFA disabled. Do you know how to correct it?
Get-MsolUser -All | Select-Object DisplayName, UserPrincipalName, @{
    Name = 'MFA Status'; 
    Expression = {
        if ($_.StrongAuthenticationRequirements.State -eq "Enforced") {
            "Enforced"
        } elseif ($_.StrongAuthenticationMethods -ne $null) {
            "Enabled"
        } else {
            "Disabled"
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv "D:\MFAStatus.csv" -NoTypeInformation

I've tried out different script and method to no avail and expect to get this scrip corrected.

Try testing for $_.StrongAuthenticationMethods.Count -gt 0 instead of $_.StrongAuthenticationMethods -ne $null

@MathiasR.Jessen I think the same is needed for StrongAuthenticationRequirements

@Nifriz I don't think so - if $_.StrongAuthenticationRequirements lists a setting that isn't enforced you might get the wrong answer by simply counting the list - in that case OP's approach would actually give the correct answer

@MathiasR.Jessen I correct my answer as you suggested.

You have to access methods in a different way, try changing the script like this:
Get-MsolUser -All | Select-Object DisplayName, UserPrincipalName, @{
    Name = 'MFA Status';
    Expression = {
        if ($_.StrongAuthenticationRequirements.State -eq "Enforced") {
            "Enforced"
        } elseif ($_.StrongAuthenticationMethods.Count -gt 0) {
            "Enabled"
        } else {
            "Disabled"
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv "D:\MFAStatus.csv" -NoTypeInformation


I’ve tried all the modifications that have been suggested so far, but I’m still seeing an ‘Enabled’ status for users with MFA disabled. And I personally visited one of these users and had him log in to his office.com account to ensure he wasn’t prompted for any authentication factor other than his password.

Try also $_.StrongAuthenticationRequirements.Count -gt 0 ‍♂️
